# How to use FIND statement along with nested IF condition

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I was trying to use the `find` statement along with `if` condition in batch, but the execution doesn't enter the `if` condition, it stops at the first `if` statement:

```
@echo off  
find /i "DA" E:\LogFiles_List.txt > nul  
pause  
if errorlevel 1  
(  
echo DA not found  
pause    
)  
else  
(  
find /i "Error" E:\hello.txt > nul   
 if errorlevel 0 (   
 echo Error found in hello.txt   
pause  
 ) else (   
 echo Error NOT found in thefile.txt   
pause  
 )   
)
```

Answer (score 0):

study the Syntax of `if`, described in `if /?`. The parantheses have to be on the same line than `if` or `else`. Here is the corrected Code:

```
@echo off  
find /i "DA" E:\LogFiles_List.txt > nul  
pause  
if errorlevel 1 (  
  echo DA not found  
  pause    
) else (  
  find /i "Error" E:\hello.txt > nul   
  if errorlevel 0 (   
    echo Error found in hello.txt   
    pause  
  ) else (   
    echo Error NOT found in thefile.txt   
    pause  
  )   
)
```